# Remove scroll effect in progress bar inside the collapsing toolbar layout in android

Tags: android, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, android-appbarlayout

I have created the `progress bar` and `toolbar` inside the `collapsing toolbar`. I set the progress bar at the top and toolbar at the `bottom` in the `layout`. The `progress bar` and `toolbar` always `scroll` or either both of them pin at top of the `layout`. But I want to pin the `progress bar` *alone* at the top, not the `toolbar` it could be scroll.

```
<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:elevation="0dp">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:titleEnabled="false"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="@android:color/white"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                app:navigationIcon="@drawable/ic_leftarrow">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/save"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="end"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                    android:text="@string/save"
                    android:textColor="@color/dim_black"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/small"
                    android:visibility="@{isVisible ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE}" />

            </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>


            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/progressBar"
                style="@style/MyProgressBar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:indeterminate="false"
                android:max="100"
                android:progress="10"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    ...
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

`

Comment: You can extract your progress bar from AppBarLayout and paste your code below AppBarLayout and above NestedScrollView

Comment: if I did like that means, Then how I place the progress bar at top of the toolbar